Image Gallery for Upload/Maintain Images in .NET Core
I have been exploring the Image Gallery control available in themarket. I have been using Aurigma, but this product is distontinued. Could someone recommend Image Gallery control in .NET Core.

I am looking for a simple interface to upload the images (no limit of the image size or number of images).
It should upport any valid image format - Including HEIC format or any other new Mobile device Image format (JPEG, PNG, WebP, SVG, HEIC and GIF - No restriction)
I should be able to change the order of images before/after uploading. As the order of Images determines in which sequence Images will be displayed. So some sort of Drap & Drop feature.
Once uploaded to the Server & entry in the SQL Server, will display Images in the chosen order.

I was experiemnting with DropZone, but to achieve all the features, it looks uphill task. Has anybody come across any reliable product, or would you recommend to build our own.

DevExtreme gallery: https://js.devexpress.com/jQuery/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/Gallery/Overview/MaterialBlueLight/ Telerik ImageGallery (there are different modes): https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/image-gallery/examples/functionality/modes/defaultcs.aspx also just google "javascript image gallery libraries"

regardless, you will need to write code. there is no "ready to go" option. for example, you will need to make the "simple interface to upload the images" yourself. shouldn't be a big deal to design a html form.

Thank you Emre for your suggestion... Yes agree, some coding will always be there to customize my needs... will explore these DevExpress & Telerik ones.

you are welcome, I also found this library called "lightbox" which seems promising, it uses Bootstrap plugins to work: https://www.lightgalleryjs.com/demos/bootstrap-image-gallery/ , https://trvswgnr.github.io/bs5-lightbox/

I found cloudinary widget extremely powerful, I do not need to create my own. Also it is cutomizable. I am able to leverage their cloud storage too.  https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_widget
I am sharing in case someone would look for these tool, it is available in .net with sample code available.
